# RData file loads into memory, then is entirely inaccessible

Tags: r, rdata

I received an .Rdata file from a colleague that I am trying to load into memory on my own server. When I attempt to use `load('./myfile.Rdata')`, everything appears to work (i.e. the machine thinks for a while and doesn't throw any error message), but then `ls()` simply returns `character(0)`.

I've tried the above, as well as trying `load('./myfile.Rdata', verbose = TRUE)` to confirm that something is happening during loading. Indeed, when I do so, I get

```
    Loading objects:
    dtn
```

`dtn` is the expected name of the object, so that's all fine and well. Again, when I then try to do anything with `dtn`, I'm told there is no such object, and `ls()` continues to return `character(0)`.

Unfortunately I can't seem to recreate the problem in any way that I can share here, short of sharing the actual file which I cannot do.

I've never experienced this problem before, and have no idea what to make of it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible, we can only guess. Maybe with `readRDS`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `readRDS` is not capable of handling `.Rdata` format, as far as I'm aware. I can't convert the file to `.rds` either since I can't read it into memory.

Comment: Is your colleague able to load it? If so, it may be worth using `saveRDS` and `readRDS` if you are only working with one object. Hopefully the error would not repeat itself.

Comment: There are many things that may be the issue. Since you didn't mention the version of R that you are using, you may need to update it if it is 3.3.X or older. There have been some changes in object file storage that could cause issues.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, everyone. I know it's hard to say without being able to replicate the issue. I was able to get a .CSV of the file which works fine. Still, if anyone has a good answer, feel free to post it for posterity's sake.